# Not creating a List in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart

Here is my point: I have two pages. The first page has a textFormField and it's value I send to the second screen. In the second screen I want to create a list of what I received from the first page. But the problem is that the list is never created. It just shows the last element received.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  final String descricao;
  const PageTwo({Key key, this.descricao}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageTwoState createState() => _PageTwoState();
}

class _PageTwoState extends State<PageTwo> {
  final List<String> listDescricao = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    listDescricao.add(widget.descricao);
    super.initState();
  }

  //List images items
  Widget imgListItem() {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listDescricao.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return widget.descricao == null
              ? Container()
              : Text(listDescricao[index]);
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: imgListItem(),
    );
  }
}
```

As required this is the **PAGE ONE**:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageOne extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageOneState createState() => _PageOneState();
}

class _PageOneState extends State<PageOne> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldkey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final inputDescricaoController = TextEditingController();

  //send image
  doSend() async {
    String descricao = inputDescricaoController.text ??= "";

    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => PageTwo(descricao: descricao)),
        (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: RaisedButton(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
                controller: inputDescricaoController,
            ),
            Text(
              'send',
            ),
          ],
        ),
        onPressed: () async {
          doSend();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add code from first page where you actually send the text to page two

Comment: You are passing only one data and adding that in the initstate method, so it should show only one value right ?
Hint 1: You may want to pass list of values from page 1
Hint 2: You know how many times initstate will be called ?

Comment: @LonelyWolf I just added the first page

Comment: @MidhunMP It will work this way: I go to page one, insert some data, and send to page two. In page two It will be saved in an array. I want to do this many times, and all this I want to display in a list, that is in page two

Comment: as @MidhunMP suggested you will have to pass list of string into page two instead of one string. If you want to go to page two every time you add a string then you will have to save the data somewhere or pass the list of string to page two, then send the list back to page one add string from the textfield to the list and pass it back to page two. Is that what you want or do you want to add all strings into list on page one and then pass ti to page two?

Comment: @LonelyWolf what I want is to pass data from page one to the page two, one at a time. But I will try what both you said ;)